# A redirection problem in my PHP proxy server for loading webpages

Tags: php, web, server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a proxy server written in PHP for a browser in a browser project, but when inside something like google.com and I tried doing a search inside the proxy server, it's going to take me to "proxyserver/search?q=hi" instead of the expected result which is "proxyserver/proxy.php?url=https://google.com/search?q=hi"

Basically the main problem is if a site rendered inside the proxy server tried taking me from /pageone to /pagetwo, it takes me from "proxyserver/proxy.php?url=https://example.com/pageone" to "proxyserver/pagetwo"

I tried pretty much everything to fix this, but it for some reason wouldn't work so I just reverted back to the old code that still has the bug.

Full code:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
session_start();

$cookieFile = 'cookies.txt';

if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    clearCookies();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    proxyRequest($url);
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $postData = http_build_query($_POST);

    echo "Debug: POST URL - " . $url . "<br>";
    echo "Debug: POST Data - " . $postData . "<br>";

    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        echo "Debug: Using GET URL - " . $url . "<br>";
    }

    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        echo "Error: Invalid URL.";
        exit;
    }

    proxyRequest($url, $postData);
} else {
    echo "Debug: Invalid request received. ";
    echo "Debug: GET Data - " . json_encode($_GET) . "<br>";
    echo "Debug: POST Data - " . json_encode($_POST) . "<br>";

    echo "Error: Invalid request.";
}

function proxyRequest($url, $postData = null) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    global $cookieFile;

    $customDNS = [
        'example.com:80:1.1.1.1',
        'example.com:443:8.8.8.8',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $options = [
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'Accept-Language: en-GB',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Dnt: 1',
            'Sec-GPC: 1',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        ],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_RESOLVE => $customDNS,
    ];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postData;
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        $options[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR] = $cookieFile;
        $options[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $cookieFile;
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($content !== false) {
        preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: (.*?);/i', $content, $matches);
        $receivedCookies = implode('; ', $matches[1]);

        file_put_contents($cookieFile, $receivedCookies);

        error_log('Received content: ' . $content);

        echo $content;
    } else {
        error_log('Error: Unable to fetch content from the external website. cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch));

        echo "Error: Unable to fetch content from the external website. cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}

function clearCookies() {
    global $cookieFile;
    if (file_exists($cookieFile)) {
        unlink($cookieFile);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh I edited the post and deleted a part of the post, and accidentally included the part where I explained what I have already tried. I've tried grabbing the url of the site rendered in the proxy server, grab the url parameters and redirect the user to "proxyserver/proxy.php?url=https:// (domain) / (file) (url parameters)" I've also tried multiple approaches in redirecting the user to proxy.php?url= but all of the attempts failed. Because of the comment character limit, I can't explain further about other ways I tried to fix the problem.

Comment: _"Because of the comment character limit, I can't explain further about other ways I tried to fix the problem."_ - you already figured out that you can _edit_ your question, so put it in there. That is where it belongs to begin with, rather than into comments.

Comment: _"I've tried grabbing the url of the site rendered"_ - what good is grabbing the URL of the site that you are _currently_ displaying, supposed to do? Your problem, with that Google search example, is that you are submitting a form with `action="/search"` - so if you are currently "on" `https://proxyserver/proxy.php?...`, then of course the browser will resolve that relative URL into `https://proxyserver/search`.

Comment: You would need to go through the source code of the Google page that your proxy requested, and _modify_ all relative URLs in there, before you output them to the browser. (Which especially for relative URLs buried somewhere in external scripts or similar, will be quite a task.)

Comment: Or, you could try and see how far inserting a [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element gets you. With that, you probably won't be able to achieve exactly the URL format you are using now - but you should be able to set the base URL to `https://proxyserver/https://google.com/`, so that when the form pointing to `/search` gets submitted, it will result in `https://proxyserver/https://google.com/search?...` If you then grab the full URL path using a bit of URL rewriting, you might have something to work with.

Comment: Or `https://proxyserver/proxy.php/https://google.com/` - then inside `proxy.php`, you should be able to get the rest of the URL path via `PATH_INFO`, and would not need additional URL rewriting for that part.